# Automate Azure SSO AD integration with snowflake

Tags: python, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to automate azure single sign on with snowflake as described in below article using python :-

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/HOW-TO-Setup-SSO-with-Azure-AD-and-the-Snowflake-New-URL-Format-or-Privatelink

I have got the microsoft graph api for the same.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-saml-sso-configure-api?tabs=http%2Cpowershell-script

However, I find it difficult to code the same scenario in python. Could anyone please help with this.

Comment: Hi - what have you tried and what specific issue are you facing? You're unlikely to find someone on this forum who is just going to write the entire script for you

Comment: @NickW I don't want entire script but if someone can provide the pointers how to go about it.